# Mongodb push to array but keep the array with a max of 3 items

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is there an easy way to push to an array in mongodb such that the array has no more than 3 items. If there are 3 items the push should throw out the first item in the array. I'm looking for a safe way to do this.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using? [2.4 perhaps?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#limit-number-of-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: @muistooshort I'm using 2.2 but am willing to upgrade if I have to.

Comment: @muistooshort now that I looked at it if you post that as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have 2.4 set up and I've never used any of that stuff for a capped array so I'm not comfortable answering. If you get something working you can answer your own question and accept that answer though, I'm happy if I've pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@muistooshort is correct.

The 2.4 $push, $each and $slice operators can be used to create a fixed length array.

You can then use the $sort operator to keep the array sorted and have the "last" item removed by the $push.

The documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/sort/#op._S_sort) has a great example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "structure type" called Capped array which is exactly made for this, which is new in 2.4 version. Here is exactly the documentation which describes the operation what you look for : [DOCS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-elements-in-updated-array/)